# Separation of variables question

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Using separation of variables solve:

$$ \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} + y \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} = (3x^2 +y)u $$

where $u(x,1) = 5e^{x^3-x}$

So I substitute the point such that

$$ \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} = (3x^2 +1)5e^{x^3-x}$$

where do I go from here?

Comment: What you did is absolutely not separation of variables.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_variables#Partial_differential_equations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$ \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} + y \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} = (3x^2 +y)
u$$

SEPARATION OF VARIABLES: We look for solutions of particular form :
$$u(x,y)=F(x)G(y)$$
$F'(x)G(y)+yF(x)G'(y)=(3x^2+y)F(x)G(y)\quad\to\quad \frac{F'}{F}+y\frac{G'}{G}=3x^2+y$

We put apart the functions of $x$ and the functions of $y$ :
$$\frac{F'}{F}-3x^2=-y\frac{G'}{G}+y=\lambda$$
A function of $x$ can be equal to a function of $y$ for any $x$ and $y$ only if those functions are constant functions. Hence $\lambda=$constant.
$$\begin{cases}
\frac{F'}{F}-3x^2=\lambda \\
-y\frac{G'}{G}+y=\lambda
\end{cases}$$
Solving both ODEs leads to :
$$\begin{cases}
F(x)=c_1e^{\lambda x+x^3}\\
G(y)=c_2e^{y-\lambda \ln(y)}
\end{cases}$$
With $c=c_1c_2$
$$u(x,y)=ce^{\lambda x+x^3+y-\lambda \ln(y)}$$
NOTE : For each value of $\lambda$, we got a different particular solution of the PDE. The general solution consists in the sum of particular solution with arbitrary coefficients.
$$u(x,y)=\int f(\lambda)e^{\lambda x+x^3+y-\lambda \ln(y)}d\lambda \qquad\text{with }f(\lambda) \text{  an arbitrary function.}$$ 
But, in the present case, we don't need to consider the general solution. 
In fact, only one particular solution is sufficient to satisfy the boundary condition (because it is a very simple textbook case).

Condition : $\quad ce^{\lambda x+x^3+1-\lambda \ln(1)}=ce^{\lambda x+x^3+1}$

$5e^{x^3-x}=ce^{1}e^{\lambda x+x^3}\quad\implies\quad
\begin{cases}5=ce \\\lambda=-1\end{cases}
\quad\to\quad u=5e^{-1}\:e^{x^3-x+y+ \ln(y)}$
$$u(x,y)=5y\,e^{-x+x^3+y-1}$$
$$ $$
IN ADDITION : Method of characteristics.

$$\frac{dx}{1}=\frac{dy}{y}=\frac{du}{(3x^2+y)u}$$
First family of characteristic curves, from $\frac{dx}{1}=\frac{dy}{y} \quad\to\quad x-\ln(y)=c_1$

Second family of characteristic curves, from $\frac{dx}{1}=\frac{dy}{y}=\frac{3x^2dx+dy}{3x^2+y}=\frac{du}{(3x^2+y)u}$

$3x^2dx+dy=\frac{du}{u} \quad\to\quad ue^{-x^3-y}=c_2$

General solution :$\quad ue^{-x^3-y}=\Phi(x-\ln(y))\quad$ any function $\Phi$.
$$u(x,y)=e^{x^3+y}\Phi(x-\ln(y)) \qquad\text{any function }\Phi(X)$$

Condition : $\quad u(x,1) = 5e^{x^3-x}=e^{x^3+1}\Phi(x-\ln(1)) =e^{x^3+1}\Phi(x)$

So, the arbitrary function is now determined : $\Phi(X)=5e^{X^3-X}e^{-X^3-1}=5e^{-X-1} $

Putting it into the general solution, with $X=x-\ln(y)$ leads to :
$$u(x,y)=e^{x^3+y}5e^{-(x-\ln(y))-1}=5ye^{x^3+y-x-1} $$

$$$$

Note: the two above methods are consistent with the relationship : $$\quad\Phi(x-\ln(y))=\int f(\lambda)e^{\lambda (x-\ln(y))}d\lambda$$

Comment: You explain this much better than my lecturer!! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

No, you should not plug $u(x,1)$ in. That is just an boundary condition to use after solving to get a specific solution. First you need to solve the differential equation.

Separation of variables in the case of PDE means that you can find a solution $u$ of the form $u(x,y) = a(x)b(y)$. If you try plugging this in you find
$$a'(x)b(y)+ya(x)b'(y) = 3x^2a(x)b(y)+ya(x)b(y) $$
and so, assuming everything works well at the denominators
$$\frac{y(b'(y)-b(y))}{b(y)} = \frac{3x^2a(x)-a'(x)}{a(x)}. $$
At the left hand side you have a function of $y$, whereas at the right you have a function of $x$. So you see, if you let $y$ vary, the right hand side remains constant, and the same happens when you let $x$ vary for the left hand side. This means 
$$\frac{y(b'(y)-b(y))}{b(y)} = \alpha$$
$$\frac{3x^2a(x)-a'(x)}{a(x)} = \beta$$
where $\alpha,\beta$ are constants. These are now linear ODE's, so you can solve them with the usual technique.